# WebCamTexture to byte[]?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, video-streaming, streaming, android-camera

I want to stream phone camera video and to do that I'm trying to convert `WebCamTexture` to `byte[]` but it appeared there's no way to do that. I can see only `GetPixels()` and `GetPixels32()` methods but I believe they're quite slow. Is there efficient way to get byte array out of webcam frame? Or am I on the wrong way?

Comment: What do you mean by stream?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I mean streaming video to another device

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done without using the [native plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html) and deep knowledge of OpenGL and Vulkan. If you target devices with OpenGL ES 3.0 or higher you can use [PBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) for asynchronous pixel transfer operations.

This is the actual read pixels function without **PBO:**

```
void ReadPixels(void* data, int textureWidth, int textureHeight)
 {

     int currentFBORead;
     int currentFBOWrite;
     glGetIntegerv(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &currentFBORead);
     glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &currentFBOWrite);

     glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, currentFBOWrite);

     glReadPixels(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);

     glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, currentFBORead);
}
```

Comment: So there's no official way to make a videostreaming using device camera, right?